# How do the Antivirus Companys find new viruses?

Tags: security, antivirus, virus

I could't found any information about Antivirus companys find new viruses?
My intention is, i would start a opensource Antivirus project for a mobile platform.

But i dont know how to setup a static signature database?
How can i find new viruses for exactly this mobile platform?

Would be great if someone could explain how big player like Norton, AVG, Kaspersky can find thousand of viruses daily.

Thank you!

Comment: I had not been aware that it is a bad question. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fundamentally malware gets sent to the anti-virus companies:

1. Customers send files detected or missed
2. Places like VirusTotal send any files detected by any engine to all the companies
3. In the showing off era, the writers would send them in themselves
4. HoneyPot systems - attacked and the results are collected
5. Email spam filters
6. Scraping infected web-pages

Comment: Thank you! That gave me a good insight.